# What is the use of BASH_REMATCH not being readonly from Bash 5.1?

Tags: bash

I read in the [release notes of Bash 5.1](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS):

> p. BASH_REMATCH is no longer readonly.

As explained in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> The array variable BASH_REMATCH records which parts of the string matched the pattern. The element of BASH_REMATCH with index 0 contains the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression. Substrings matched by parenthesized subexpressions within the regular expression are saved in the remaining BASH_REMATCH indices. The element of BASH_REMATCH with index n is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.

And yes, it is very useful to access the matches of a regular expression:

```
$ DESERT=pie-cake_berry_cream-sirup
$ [[ $DESERT =~ _(.*)_ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
berry
```

However, I cannot see what is the use of this news in Bash 5.1. That is, what is the point of BASH_REMATCH not being readonly?

Comment: I assume making the array modifiable outweighed the effort to make a copy of the array or to define a more complicated regular expression to avoid matching a particular substring in the first place.

Comment: The array was never *truly* read-only, as each subsequent match overwrote the previous value.

Comment: I think [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-10/msg00075.html) is the relevant mailing list thread, with a request from the bashdb author.

Comment: @BenjaminW. great find, thanks! Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, let me see if I understand it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this bug-bash mailing list thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-10/msg00075.html), the maintainer of [bashdb](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/) (a Bash debugger) explains that the value of `BASH_REMATCH` might change inside a debug hook, and since the variable is read-only, resetting it happens by running the command that initially set it again, which is tricky and fragile:

> Current in bash 5.0 and earlier, the value of BASH_REMATCH might chanted inside a debug hook.
>
> Since BASH_REMATCH is read-only, resetting the value on hook return to the debugged program is a bit tricky and fragile...
>
> [...]
>
> The way that bashdb currently resets BASH_REMATCH is to reissue the command that caused the value to get initially set. That is fragile since this set on exit between stepping from the time BASH_REMATCH was set until the time it is last used. In between variables used in the regular expression may have changed.
>
> [...]
>
> Restoring it is just as tricky. As I hope you see all of this is a bit fragile.

In the [response](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-10/msg00076.html), Chet offers to make it not read-only:

> How about we just make it not read-only? The shell will still set it when it does regexp matching.